# Jquery.get cannot retrieve XML from RESTful Service

Tags: jquery, xml, rest, timeout, get

I'm trying to get an XML document from a REST service using the Jquery get method, but it doesn't seem to be able to download. After only about 11 seconds, the connection dies and I receive a blank document. I've tested out the URL by accessing it through the browser, and it works (even though it takes 4 minutes to load).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.get(
        siteUrl,
        function(data) { parseXml(data); }
    );
});
```

I've considered using the ajax method, because you can set the timeout, but the same domain policy applies, restricting me from using it. Any ideas?

Comment: No, but according to RomanArmy, if .get is just shorthand for the ajax function, then it makes sense why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, .get and .ajax will not work since they are not under the same domain, thus violating the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

To get around this, we can use the .getJson method (more information found on [IBM's site](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/))

However, in my situation, the desired output is not Json, thus we can use something like [YQL from Yahoo to accomplish](http://www.wait-till-i.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/)... or just use a proxy server on your domain.

Comment: @Anton: BTW, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ is also just a wrapper around the ajax call.  It only gets treated as jsonp if you have a `callback=?` on the end of the url.

Comment: That's right. With the YQL, you have to add that to your URL, so it should still be fine.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation for [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

> This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

So I'm not sure what you mean by *"but the same domain policy applies, restricting me from using it."* But if `$.get` works, so will `$.ajax`